# Interrupt a slow gdb command?

Tags: signals, gdb, sigint

I unwisely asked `gdb` to list all defined functions.

```
(gdb) info function
```

Now it is excitedly slurping up CPU and memory. If I'm really quick about it, GDB will stop with Ctrl-C and give me a prompt again.

```
(gdb) info functions
^CQuit
(gdb)
```

But if I'm too slow, it won't respond to Ctrl-C (SIGINT), Ctrl-\ (SIGQUIT), or SIGTERM.

```
(gdb) info functions
^C^C^\
```

Oddly enough, GDB does respond to SIGUSR1.

```
(gdb) info functions
^C^C^\User defined signal 1
```

However, this ends my GDB session and I have to start all over again. Is there another way to halt a slow-running command that doesn't kill GDB entirely?

For the record, I'm running GDB version 7.12.0.20161007-git on Debian 9.3 (stretch).